# positioning of axis-ticks and -labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, axis, axis-labels

Probably it's quite straight forward, but I wasn't able to solve it yet.

I produced following 3d plot:

[image]

I don't like how the axis ticks and axis labels are aligned.

from another perspective:

[image]

I would prefer having the axis-labeling on the same corresponding plane and the tick-labels aligned with the grid of the plot. Somehow similar to this one I found:

[image]

My plot configuration is quite simple as I deleted all of the parameters I tried to reach such changes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')

plt.tight_layout(pad=1, w_pad=1, h_pad=3.0)

ax.set_xlabel('sample size R', ha = 'center',) 
ax.set_ylabel('method', ha = 'center',) 
ax.set_zlabel('total',  ) 

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 210)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 4)
ax.set_zlim3d(80, 200)

ax.set_xticks([1, 50, 100, 150, 200])
ax.set_yticks([0, 1, 2, 3 ])
ax.set_zticks([80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200])

ax.set_yticklabels(labels = ["DAC", "DMC-nf ", "AMC-95", "DA-w/o"], ha = 'left', 
                            verticalalignment = 'baseline',) 

ax.set_xticklabels(labels =[1, 50, 100, 150, 200] , ha = 'center', 
                            verticalalignment = 'baseline', )  
ax.set_zticklabels(labels =[80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200] , ha = 'center', 
                            verticalalignment = 'baseline',) 

ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad= -3, direction = 'out' ,)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', direction = 'out' )

ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

plt.show()
```

Comment: It is the opposite of "straight forward", it is impossible.  Matplotlib lays out text in 2-D whereas the plot you have lays it out in 3-D.  It would be cool if Matplotlib could do that, but it is fundamentally meant to work on vector backends where this sort of rendering is not possible.  OTOH, if you dropped your angle down in the fully 3-D plot you wouldn't be able to read the axis tick labels at all, so not sure that is really what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer! that makes quite some sense, even if i had hoped for a different answer :)